# Problema conexión BD Oracle SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

Tengo un problema al tratar de conectarme a la base de datos, desde un usuario en específico, a través de sqlplus.

Si ejecuto `sqlplus / as sysdba` me conecto sin problemas:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 16 16:38:54 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Pero si trato usando `sqlplus usuario/contraseña@SID`, no puedo conectarme:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 16 16:43:03 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Enter user-name:
```

Pero si coloco las credenciales nuevamente, si me llega a conectar.

Solo tengo una instancia de base de datos en el servidor, tengo definidas las variables ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, tengo la ruta bin y la lib cargadas en las variables del sistema.

Comment: Mira este enlace: [ORA-01034: ORACLE Not Available tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01034_oracle_not_available.htm) o también puedes consultar: `ORA-01034 + sqlplus`. Sin conocer mas de Oracle, yo diría que te puede faltar alguna variable de configuración.

Comment: Seguí los pasos que se detallan en el enlace, pero aún sin éxito @MauricioAriasOlave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo listener.ora ubicado en *ORACLE_HOME/network/admin* me faltaba configurar el SID_LIST_LISTENER, el cual se asigna de la siguiente forma:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC =
     (ORACLE_HOME =Ruta_Oracle_Home)
     (SID_NAME = SID)
   )
 )
```

luego de esto reinicié el listener: `lsnrctl stop` - `lsnrctl start` y pude conectarme sin problemas.